# Are there countries other than Israel which are regularly described in terms of their ethnic nature?

Tags: israel, demographics

In Western parlance, and in particular among supporters of Israel, it is common to describe Israel as "the Jewish state." For instance, here is [one](https://www.adl.org/resources/news/adl-and-israel) example from the ADL.

> "In addition, we work to educate on why one-sided and biased approaches to the complex Israeli-Palestinian conflict, as well as campaigns aimed at delegitimizing **the Jewish state** – including the Boycott, Divestment and Sanctions (BDS) movement - are unconstructive and even damaging to the hopes for ultimate peace. Such campaigns can also create an environment in which Jews who feel connected to Israel may feel isolated or beleaguered, and can also embolden those who seek to engage in antisemitic rhetoric or actions."

This example is but one of many.

I find this emphasis on the ethnic nature of the state, even at the expense of English efficiency (one word "Israel" versus three words "the Jewish state"), rather interesting. I also find it unique in that, to my knowledge, no other states are referred to in such starkly ethnic terms. For instance, China is never called "the Han state" and Iran is never called "the Persian state."

**Are there other examples in English where a country is routinely referred to by an "ethnic monicker" as opposed to its actual name?**

Comment: The Israeli concept of the nation is indeed unique among nation states. See this similar question: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82628/are-there-countries-besides-israel-that-declare-themselves-nation-states-for-a/ The usage of the phrase "the Jewish state" underscores ADL's belief that Israel has the right to exist *as a Jewish state*.

Comment: This is a [duplicate](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82628/are-there-countries-besides-israel-that-declare-themselves-nation-states-for-a).

Comment: @wrod Not a duplicate as this focuses specifically on "the Jewish state" terminology. The UK for instance is a "nation state" but does not employ e.g., "the Anglo-Saxon state" terminology in reference to itself.